# Highchart Disable stackLabels when overflow

Tags: html, highcharts, responsive-design

Hello i have a chart like in the example http://goo.gl/z4joLo

Try lowering the chart area and note that the total labels overlaps itself.
I would like to set stackLabel.enabled property to false (hide total label) when it occurs.
How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [redraw()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event, iterate over each stacklabels and check width and position of box. If neighbours overlap, then destroy element.